# How to understand the scaling in Metropolis Hastings MCMC

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

We know the Metropolis Hastings (MH) in MCMC:

- target distribution: $\pi(x)$
- proposal distribution: $p(y|x)$
- acceptance: $\alpha(x,y) = \min \Big(1, \dfrac{\pi(y)p(y|x)}{\pi(x)p(x|y)}\Big)$

Here are some examples of a proposal distribution:

- $p(y|x)$ density of $U(x-\sigma, x+\sigma)$
- $p(y|x)$ density of $N(x,\sigma^2).$

Then how to understand the statements that:

1. **large $\alpha$ or $\sigma^2$ will lower the acceptance;**
2. **small  $\alpha$ or $\sigma^2$ will increase the correlation.**

I cannot mathematically deduce the result from the acceptance formula.

Comment: The intuition is that if your chain at iteration $i$ is $x_{i}$ and you propose a candidate that it is near $x^{'}_{cand}=x_{i}+0.1$ ($a$ small and $\sigma^{2}$ small) it is more likely  to be accepted than a candidate $x_{cand}^{'}=x_{i}+1000$ ($a$ big and $\sigma^{2}$ big). So, obviously in the first case  if you accept your candidate you will have higher correlation because it is almost the same with your $x_{i}$

Comment: @Fiodor1234 agree on the  intuition, actually I want to see the mathematical proof, especially for the first one.

Comment: Sure, I think I can demonstrate one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a target distribution with unrestricted support $\mathfrak X$, consider the simple random walk proposal written as
$$y=x+\sigma\epsilon\,,$$
where $\epsilon$ is a unit-variance symmetric white noise. Then
$$\dfrac{\pi(y)p(y|x)}{\pi(x)p(x|y)}=\dfrac{\pi(y)}{\pi(x)}=\dfrac{\pi(x+\sigma\epsilon)}{\pi(x)}$$
which a.s. converges to $1$ when $\sigma$ goes to zero and to $0$ when $\sigma$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Sorry I cannot convince by above deduction, you should proof $P\Big(U\leq \min(1,\dfrac{\pi(x+\sigma\epsilon)}{\pi(x)})\Big)$ is an decreasing function of  $\sigma.$

Comment: "to 0 when $\sigma$ goes to infinity" why?

Comment: The property does not hold for all $\sigma$'s but only for small enough and large enough $\sigma$'s.

Comment: even for the large enough $\sigma,$ why goes to 0? Or everything here is "almost surely"?

Comment: That the density goes to zero at infinity is a necessary condition for the density to be integrable.

Comment: when $\sigma$ is small, the generated states are highly correlated. Then why do we say the high correlation states will slow the convergence?

Comment: The higher the correlation the larger the variance of a Monte Carlo estimator like $\sum_{t=1}^T h(x_t)/T$, hence the larger the number of simulations $T$ needed to achieve a given precision.